# Distributing equipment that uses BSD3 licensed software

Tags: bsd

I have inspected bsd3 license and it seems like a good permissive license for open source software.

However I have a question:
Do I need to distribute licensing of a software that I have used (bsd3 here) to develop a hardware? I will be distributing the hardware and software will not be acquired separately from the equipment.

An example would be like a open source bsd3 crc library that is used within the internal boot loader of a smart air drier. Does the company need to disclose licensing of the crc library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume the bootloader is part of every device and the CRC run when it is starting up: Yes you have to - or you would have no license to use it.

The BSD license is not too complicated (I abridged the disclaimer):

> Copyright 2042 Amazing Company
>
> Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
> modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are
> met:
>
> 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
> 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
>    documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
> 3. Neither the name of the copyright holder nor the names of its contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived from
>    this software without specific prior written permission.
>
> THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY (...)
> OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.

I take the bootloader is part of the device you distribute; that means you distribute the software in binary form. And that means that clause §2 kicks in: you must notify your users about the software and copyright.

The means is not given as it would be difficult to say so for all possible cases. For an embedded device without direct user interface it probably should go into the user documentation you ship along with your device.

If you have some user interface (smart might imply this), you can provide an about option. For guidance look at your own phone. You will find some 'about' or 'licenses' section somewhere in the UI and settings where you can review the licensing of all the many libraries and programmes which make up the OS and related services of it. E.g. on my phone I find all these in listed by service under 'about' -> 'legal notes' -> '3rd party licenses'. Similarily you could look how your browser handles this.

If I read your question wrong and it is only a tool used to create the software and not installed or uploaded on the device (like a compiler), then no, tools are not part of what is being distributed.

Answer (score 2):

It's common for binaries to create text files of the given license and attributions. While it's true that many applications have ui elements that display licenses, not all do. Specifically, some licenses permit clauses where as condition to using the software you *must* provide some form of conspicuous notice of the license and attributions, where BSD just states "you must reproduce" without implying what form that reproduction must take (other than the actual text of the license) or how the user must be able access it.

In general, distributors are not the only one bound by the terms of the various licenses of the software in a system they distribute, their users/clients are as well. You must provide reasonable access to such licenses and should require clients to accept the terms of those licenses as well as the terms of your own license. Otherwise, if at any point the client (or even their own clients/customers, etc) falls out of compliance with the terms of such license the client can claim they were not aware of the existence those terms.

Update: Additionally, open source licenses generally revolve around terms to permit modifying and redistributing the software, with generally little to no terms that extend to users in cases were the user is literally just using the software without actually copying. Even in cases where a notice must be made available to users, the user isn't required to view the element, it just must be reasonably visible. Even this is generally for attribution rather than any form of agreement on the users part. If I'm not mistaken, it only becomes important to make the license and attribution visible with most licenses when a user begins to directly interface with or otherwise use features explicitly relevant to the software unless otherwise stated in the license.

In your example, if the user just presses an 'On' button and the air dryer magically begins to operate, it is doubtful that the user would need to see the BSD license because the software isn't providing function that is explicitly relevant to the users operation of the dryer. As the user presses other buttons to change humidity, temperature, etc, the bootloader becomes even more irrelevant to the operation of the dryer. However, if the user is able to interface with the dryer in a way that they can instruct the bootloader to boot the dryer in a different state, such as to allow them to access some advanced mode to program it, the bootloader then provides functionality directly relevant to the use of the dryer. In this case the user should likely have the license made available and should have some form visible of attribution.

Interestingly, a Ubuntu user may never now that Grub is on their system until they configure a duel-boot, or instruct Ubuntu to restart in a state where they can choose to boot into safemode using Grub. At this point they will be met with a screen heading that says "GNU Grub", but Ubuntu doesn't need to print the GPL to the screen to satisfy the terms. It is within Grubs rights to add a clause to require that a menu option be made available to for users to view attributions and it's license and still be compatible with the GPL, but Grub doesn't have such a clause and you won't find Grubs license unless you look for it. But the license is in fact available on every copy of each Ubuntu distribution, even if Ubuntu is pre-installed.